# Setting my app api aware and preventing system to make it blurry and wrongly positioned

Tags: c++, winapi, dpi-aware

I have a simple app with a parent window and 4 child windows. It looks fine on `Windows xp` and`Windows 7` to `125%`display settings.

However, on `Windows 7` more than `125%` and `Windows 10` `125%` itself , windows , menu , text and message boxes gets blurry and child windows get overflowed.

I want to fix them so that they look fine so i tried to replace their sizes with updated sizes according to dpi:

```
//Get resoulation 
int resX=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN) , resY=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
//Get current dpi
HDC screen = GetDC(0);
int dpiX = GetDeviceCaps(screen, LOGPIXELSX);
int dpiY = GetDeviceCaps(screen, LOGPIXELSY);
//Do some calculations about the resoulation 
if( resX <= 800 ){
        winWidth=resX/1.45;
        winHeight=resY/1.3;
    }
//...

//Update width and height of the main window according to the current dpi
int updatedWinWidth=(winWidth * dpiX) / 96 , updatedWinHeight=(winHeight * dpiY) / 96 ;
//Creating parent window with updated width and height
hwnd=CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE , myClassName , L"Compressor Reporter" ,  WS_OVERLAPPED  | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU ,CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,  updatedWinWidth , updatedWinHeight, NULL , NULL , hInstance , NULL );

//Updating width and height for child window, width and height variables are the dafault width and height for the child 
int updatedWidth = ( width * dpiX) / 96 , updatedHeight= (height * dpiY) / 96;
//Creating the child window
hwndList1 = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" ,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER  | WS_VSCROLL | LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED, middle-(10+updatedWidth) , middleH-(10+updatedHeight) , updatedWidth , updatedHeight, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); 



//Font settings
HDC hdc=GetDC( hHeader1);
int points=0;
switch(GetDeviceCaps( hdc , LOGPIXELSY)){
    case 96:
        points=11;
        break;
    default:
        points=10.5;
}

int fonth=-MulDiv(points, GetDeviceCaps( hdc , LOGPIXELSY) , 72 );

ReleaseDC(hHeader1 , hdc);

hF2=CreateFont(fonth, 0, 0, 0, FW_BOLD, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, L"Tahoma");

SendMessage(hHeader1,WM_SETFONT,(WPARAM)hF2,MAKELPARAM(TRUE,0));
```

However , the result is the same.

I also change the `Compressor Reporter.exe.embed.manifest` and add the `application` tag inside it as follow. But when i rebuilt my app , what i added unappears and i see there isnt the `application` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
 <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
        <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <security>
   <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix the blurry windows , text , menu and messageBoxes and make the child windows to position correctly?

Thanks

Comment: That manifest is generated each time you build based on project settings.  Take a look at the manifest settings in project settings, they might let you set DPI aware.  If not you could turn off automatic manifest generation.

Comment: I'll respond with more stuff later today.  Can you provide an [mcve] with a sample source file (that has a WinMain, creates a window, etc...) and vcxproj set?

Comment: @Dave S Thanks so much that was all..

Answer (score 3):

You may have missed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> Desktop applications using older Windows programming technologies (raw
>   Win32 programming, Windows Forms, Windows Presentation Framework
>   (WPF), etc.) are unable to automatically handle DPI scaling without
>   additional developer work. Without such work, applications will appear
>   blurry or incorrectly-sized in many common usage scenarios.

In order to update an existing desktop application to handle DPI scaling properly, it needs to be updated such that, at a minimum, the important parts of its UI are updated to respond to DPI changes.

Most desktop applications run under system DPI awareness mode. System-DPI-aware applications typically scale to the DPI of the primary display (the display that the system tray was located on at the time the Windows session was started). When the DPI changes, Windows will bitmap stretch the UI of these applications, which often results in them being blurry. When updating a System DPI-aware application to become per-monitor-DPI aware, the code which handles UI layout needs to be updated such that it is performed not only during application initialization, but also whenever a DPI change notification ([WM_DPICHANGED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/wm-dpichanged) in the case of Win32) is received. This typically involves revisiting any assumptions in the code that the UI only needs to be scaled once.

You can understand how it works with the help of the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#example).

Don't forget to add `SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE)` which changes the DPI awareness while the app is running.

Cases may useful:

- [High-DPI Scaling Improvements for Desktop Applications in the
  Windows 10 Creators Update (1703)](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/)
- [Per-window DPI Awareness Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DPIAwarenessPerWindow)

Comment: @Code-Lover hi, does this answer useful to you? If you have any question, please feel free to tell me:)